# How to pass a list to callback method in telethon?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I'm working on a callback function in [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon), my code is something like this:

```
def callback(update):
    channel_entity = client.get_entity('myzoomg') #Get specific Channel information
    update.message.to_id.channel_id == channel_entity.id: #Check message from that specific channel
        # do something

client.add_update_handler(callback)
client.idle()  # ends with Ctrl+C
client.disconnect()
```

I want to pass a parameter as a list item to [`get_entity`](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/wiki/Working-with-Updates) method, something like this:

```
channel_entity = client.get_entity(channel_list[0])
```

This objective normally is accessible by passing `channel_list` as argument to `callback` method, but actually `callback` method just takes update argument as input. My question is how to pass a list to this method?